# I cannot receive Salesforce Alert in Slack Channel at specific time

Tags: integration, time

I have completed the integration between Salesforce and Slack. But I only can receive alerts between **12AM - 12PM in CST**(Chinese Standard Time) at weekdays, or **all days** at weekends. Is there anyone meets this issue?

This is a really strange issue. I asked the Slack support, and they tell me that this is an issue with your team's Salesforce environment rather than the Slack package. So is there any function which will impact integration execution time?

Comment: Maybe check login hours against the users profile?

Comment: Thanks Phil for your comment. This issue happened on every user in our org. And I check the login hours, there is no login hours specified.